# Is there a way for me to make this function return only the number of input fields with the class "Calctime' that are not null?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an airport application that records the time it takes to get from one airport to another. Going from one Airport to another is called a Sector and the time it takes to get from airport to another is known as Block time. I have made my form in such a way that you can fill a total of 8 Sectors. The problem now is before I press the submit button I want the field called # of Sectors to display the total number of only filled out sectors. It will do this by checking how many fields with the class 'Calctime' are not null. All fields called Block Time have this class of 'Calctime'.

[The form with a total of 8 Sectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIOFG.png)

Here is the function I created, as it stands this function is returning the total number of fields which is 8 instead of only filled up fields:

```
function sectors(){
 var items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.calctime')]; //demo to count number of empty
 document.getElementById('sector').value = items.length
 }
```

Comment: `not null` you mean, not empty? I don't think an input field value can be `null` can it?

Comment: Do you have any question about this code? Are you sure this problem is related to CSS? Please share more details, and add all of them to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over these form fields and check their values.

```js
function sectors(){
 var items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.calctime')]; //demo to count number of empty
 let filledFields=0;
 items.forEach(item => {
     if(item.value) filledFields++;
 })
 document.getElementById('sector').value = filledFields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a placeholder (even an empty one) to the inputs, you can use `querySelectorAll('element:not(:placeholder-shown))` to select all unfilled inputs.

For accessibility reasons, you should use a placeholder anyways!

```js
// function to count filled inputs
function countFilledInputs() {
  let filled_inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.calctime:not(:placeholder-shown)');
  console.log(filled_inputs.length);
}


// eventListeners for demo purposes
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', countFilledInputs);
const INPUTS = document.querySelectorAll('input.calctime');
INPUTS.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', countFilledInputs));
```

```html
<input class="calctime" placeholder="">
<input class="calctime" placeholder="">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want filtered list by had a value
you can use array.property.filter method
here is example

```js
 button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
   let items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.calctime')];  
   const button = document.getElementById('button')
   items = items.filter((item) => !!item.value )

   document.getElementById('sector').value = items.length
 })
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="calctime" />
  <input type="text" class="calctime" />
  <input type="text" class="calctime" />
  <input type="text" class="calctime" />
  <input type="text" class="calctime" />
  <input type="text" class="calctime" />
  <input type="text" class="calctime" />
  <input type="text" class="calctime" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="sector" readonly />
  <button id="button">button</button>
</div>
```